# Size Mismatch Between Swing Fonts and Printable Fonts in Java

Tags: java, printing, jtextpane

I've got a panel displaying a JTextPane backed by a StyledDocument.  When I print a string of text in, say Arial 16, the text it prints is the same size as the Arial 16 Word prints.  However, the Arial 16 in the JTextPane appears to be smaller than the Arial 16 Word displays.  Is there some sort of flaw in the translation of Swing fonts to Windows system fonts or something of the sort that makes it difficult (or impossible) to print accurately?

I can achieve an approximation by scaling down the size of my font before printing, but this never quite gets me the results I would like, as it's not possible in all cases to reproduce things like equivalent numbers of words on a line, etc.

Has anybody run into this before?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Caleb.  Could you post some code?  My first thoughts are that you're not printing at the resolution you expect, or that your printer is doing some kind of auto-scale-to-paper-size thing.  Or did you mean printing to the screen?

Comment: Sorry, I made a bit of a typo.  I've corrected it above.  The problem is that Arial 16 appears smaller in a JTextPane than it does in Word, and therefore prints something I don't expect in a larger looking, but correct, font.  There may be something going on with the printing end of things, but this is the most important problem.  If you still think some code would be helpful, let me know.

Comment: Btw, I just found this:

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5423031

Comment: That link looks good.  Did it answer your question?

Comment: Not really :-(  I've tried to do some scaling down of printed fonts, and this is a decent approximation, but it seems impossible to get the printed output to match my text pane line for line.  I still get two different "Arial 16"s, even after scaling.

If you read to the bottom of the post, DReese seems to say that there is currently no way to get the Swing component fonts and system fonts to appear the same.  This is what I'm really afraid of.  It seems like something there might not be a work-around for...

Comment: Yeah, I intentionally asked "did it answer your question" rather than "did it solve your problem."  I vaguely remembered some Word problems from a while ago, but the URL you found seems like a much better explanation.